# Relevance of StartUp Project with VSTO

Tags: c#, vb.net, vsto

Under a Solution which contains several Projects, one of them being a VSTO, is there any relevance in determining a Project as being "StartUp"?

The ThisAddin_Startup() `Sub` will trigger when the Office Application is open, so what would be the point to define a StartUp? Maybe for build/compiling purposes?

Comment: What other kind of projects are we talking about and what's the expected behavior of the solution? Are the non-VSTO projects things that VSTO works with? Normally, no, you wouldn't set anything. When it's built and installed the VSTO project is written to the Windows Registry. The Office application finds it there and loads it, automatically.

Comment: Under the context of that question, lets say we only have one VSTO Project, and some DLL (Class Library) Projects. In reality I am considering having several VSTO Projects in the same Spolution (1 Excel VSTO + 1 Word VSTO). But we are getting off topic here and I will treat that subject in a separate question.

Comment: Well, a DLL can't be a "start up" - a DLL doesn't run independently. So, again, no, nothing would be set as the "startup". Also shouldn't matter whether the solution has two different add-ins, as long as the installtion is registering both correctly in the Windows Registry.

Comment: I have found that when I have two VSTO AddIn Projects within the same Solution, setting the Word VSTO as StartUp will launch Word when starting Debugging, or will launch the Excel VSTO if the later was set to StartUp.